# Lua - nil value

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I get the following error message from Corona SDK : attempt to call field "ImageSheet" (a nil value) stack traceback. Can somebody point out the mistake?

```
   local ISPar = {
    width = 2541,
    height = 264,
    numFrames = 7
 }
local ImageSheet = graphics.ImageSheet("Apus.png, ISPar")

local ApusSequenceData = {
  {name = "fly", frames {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, time = 800, loopCount = 0}
  }

local Apus = display.newSrpite(ImageSheet, ApusSequenceData)
Apus.x = display.contentWidth/2
Apus.y = display.contentHeight/2
Apus:play()
```

Comment: should be `graphics.newImageSheet`, also missing `=` for frames key in table.

Comment: also youll need to fix  the quotes in your arguments (`"Apus.png", ISPar`) and typo in `display.newSprite`. Avoid using capitalized names for variables as they may shadow class names, and are otherwise unconventional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the function name wrong, it was supposed to be graphics.newImageSheet. Also you misplaced the quotation marks when calling it. And afterwards you misspelt newSprite

This code should work:

```
local ISPar = {
    width = 2541,
    height = 264,
    numFrames = 7
}
local ImageSheet = graphics.newImageSheet("Apus.png", ISPar)

local ApusSequenceData = {{name = "fly", frames = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, time = 800, loopCount = 0}}

local Apus = display.newSprite(ImageSheet, ApusSequenceData)
Apus.x = display.contentWidth/2
Apus.y = display.contentHeight/2
Apus:play()
```

Comment: Only there should be "=" after frames, otherwise the code is perfect. Tanks.

Comment: @DFrogBinder Oops, sorry about that, that's one mistake I didn't catch lol. Glad I was able to help :)